# Manga in which the main character fought a dragon and died, but was sent back in time to when he was a student at an academy

Tags: story-identification, manga, dragons

I forgot the name of a manga I was reading. It was relatively new, I will try to summarize what I read to the best of my memory.

The main character (MC) fought a dragon and died but was sent back in time to when he was at an academy that trains their students to kill dragons. He showed the teacher he was proficient at the sword, great sword, and spear.

He became friends with a muscle head who was skilled at hand-to-hand combat. The MC had learned hand-to-hand combat from him in the future and made his own movement technique based off his friend's tribe's techniques.

Along with that friend, he also made friends with a redhead fire mage. The last thing I remember is that his brother disappeared during a fight with a dragon with control over dimensions, and was not present in the new past the MC was in.

That is all I can remember about the story.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: I believe this was in full color from what I saw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[My Little Brother Is The Academy’s Hotshot](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/my-little-brother-is-the-academys-hotshot)***.

> In the last battle with the king of the dragon race that killed countless humans, Rudd Denatos loses his comrades and biological elder brother, Aesir Denatos. The moment he slays an unidentified dragon that appears before him, he returns to his days as an academy cadet. However, his brother, Aesir, a genius warrior doesn’t exist in the past world Rudd has regressed into. Trying to fill in the empty spot of Aesir, Rudd tries to prepare as much as possible before the strongest dragon king, the Seventh Dragon, appears. Will Rudd be able to find his older brother and avenge his parents?

I'm pretty sure this manhwa is what you're looking for. I've read it and matches what you are looking for exactly.

Comment: Welcome to Scifi.SE! Can you go into a bit more detail about *how* it matches OP's description?

Comment: I believe this is it! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Doubtful hi and welcome to the site (also welcome to Ferrow)! Doubtful, you can upvote and mark this as correct if you're certain it's correct. See more about how to do that in [tour] and [help] and specifically [Accepted answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is *A Returner's Magic Should Be Special*

the first chapter is a group defeating a dragon, which explodes awhile after being defeated. the main character then appears in his past, on his first day at Havrion Academy.

It is in full color,